# ASP.NET grid view SelectedValue is getting null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, debugging, null

I'm having problems with a ASP NET grid view, I allways use the Default Select Button in grid views, the problem is that this time is not working.

The only diference i can tell is that now i'm using a Datatable for DataSource. (instead of a List<>).

**HTML code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgv_cursos_materia" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgv_cursos_materia_SelectedIndexChanged1" SelectedIndex="0">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID Materia" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_comision" HeaderText="Comision" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="anio_calendario" HeaderText="Año " />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cupo" HeaderText="Cupo" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**C# code:**

```
protected void dgv_cursos_materia_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.ViewState["curso"] = (int)this.dgv_cursos_materia.SelectedValue; // - Error is here. SelectedValue gets null.

        this.lbl_test.Text = this.ViewState["curso"].ToString();
    }
```

I dont know why this is not working for me. I did the same with other two grid view on the same Form and they work.. 
As i told you, it's the first as I use a Datatable to "fill" the Grid view.

My problem is that SelectedValue gets null.

Sorry for my English, hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with [SelectedRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
protected void dgv_cursos_materia_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dgv_cursos_materia.SelectedRow;
    var id =  (int)row.Cells[0].Text
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried but its tells me that the index was out of interval.

Answer (score 0):

I had copied your code and fill the grid view with data table it works perfectly fine for me and get id as my selected value in lbl_test.Text;

Below is my code,

For cs file :-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = FlyingPopDataHandler.getFlyingPopCityAndStateName("MX4TX9GPCFP0MNU");
        dgv_cursos_materia.DataSource = dt;
        dgv_cursos_materia.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void dgv_cursos_materia_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.ViewState["curso"] = (string)this.dgv_cursos_materia.SelectedValue; 

    this.lbl_test.Text = this.ViewState["curso"].ToString();
}
```

For aspx file:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgv_cursos_materia" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="campaign_id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgv_cursos_materia_SelectedIndexChanged1" SelectedIndex="0">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="campaign_id" HeaderText="FpId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="state" HeaderText="state" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_test" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Try this way may solve your problem,
verify your code with the above code is there any mistake to take any data in data table particularly `id` field of database?
just check it once.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer.
I checked but it seems like there is not problem with the Datatable, because i use the same method to fill a data grid view on a Desktop proyect. I think the problem may be is on the "select button" on the grid view.

Comment: can you send me screen shot where you got any error.